# Is it possible to invite people with Discord.js outside the server?

Tags: javascript, api, discord.js

I am working with Signavio Workflow Accelerator and I am modelling a process about employee onboarding. In this process I have to implement a Rest-API. The new employee should type his Discord name/E-Mail and he will get automatically an invite-link to his e-mail to join the Discord server. I have to implement it with JavaScript.

I wanted to ask whether this is possible, if so how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You can manually create a single invite that lasts forever and has infinite uses, you can use the to be sent to every employee!

Comment: Yes, but my professor said me, that he wants a individual invite link for the process, I forget to tell it.

Comment: @SüleymanDemir You would need to create a discord bot then, I've plent experience in this field if you message me on discord i can help you out! my discord is KeemROH#9436, alternatively you can join my server http://discord.keemroh.tech/